# ¿Cómo resolver problema de recursividad con dos entidades con Spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, java-8, recursión

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Spring Boot en el que tengo 2 entidades que me ocasionan problemas. Tengo una entidad *Empleado* y otra *Sucursal* y en la primera tengo una propiedad llamada *sucursal* que indica la sucursal donde trabaja y, por su parte, la entidad sucursal tiene una lista de empleados, además de otra propiedad llamada *gerente* de tipo ***Empleado***. Hay algo que no estoy tomando en cuenta de quién es el que ocasiona la recursividad.

```
// Entidad Empleado
@Entity
@Table(name="empleado")
public class Empleado extends Persona implements Serializable {
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="legajo")
    private long legajo;

    @Column(name="sueldo_basico")
    private double sueldoBasico;

   // Otras propiedades

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_sucursal", nullable=false)
    private Sucursal sucursal;

   // Getters y setters



// Entidad Sucursal
@Entity
@Table(name="sucursal")
public class Sucursal implements Serializable {
    @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_sucursal")
    private long idSucursal;

    @Column(name="nombre", nullable=false, length=50)
    private String nombre;

   // Otras propiedades

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "gerente_legajo", referencedColumnName = "legajo")
    private Empleado gerente;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="sucursal")
    private Set<Empleado> listaEmpleados;

   // Getters y setters
```

Lo siguiente es una parte de lo que me arroja al, por ejemplo, ver el listado de empleados:

*at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.0.rc1.jar:2.11.0.rc1]*

Había leído algo de corregir el problema utilizando anotaciones como *@JsonIgnore* y *@JsonBackReference*, pero no sé aún como podría implementarlas.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas agregar @JsonManagedReferences y @JsonBackReferences, se utilizan para mostrar objetos con relación padre-hijo. @JsonManagedReferences se usa para referirse al objeto padre y @JsonBackReferences se usa para marcar objetos hijos.Esas anotaciones seran suficiente para resolver el estado de recursividad que esta ocurriendo en tus entidades.

Para mas informacion puedes consultar https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson_annotations/jackson_annotations_jsonbackreference.htm